# Attempting to retrieve refresh token with OpenIddict gives Internal Server Error

Tags: openiddict, refresh-token

I'm trying to obtain access and refresh tokens using the OpenIddict library.

Everything seems fine when requesting an access token.  But when adding scope = offline_access, a 500 Internal Server Error is returned.

Using Postman with grant_type = password, and a username and password set, a valid access_token is returned.

But after appending scope = offline_access, the status is 500 Internal Server Error.

I register the OpenIddict services with

```
services.AddOpenIddict(options => {
    options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<dbContext>();
    options.AddMvcBinders();
    options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");
    options.AllowPasswordFlow();
    options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
    options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
    options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
});
```

I register OpenIddict and the validation middleware

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseOAuthValidation(options => {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    });

    app.UseOpenIddict();

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

and create a token authentication controller

```
[HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
{
    if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
            user.Id.ToString,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                new AuthenticationProperties(),
                OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            ticket.SetResources(request.GetResources());
            ticket.SetScopes(request.GetScopes());

            return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);    
    }
}
```

The error goes away if the SetScopes call is removed, but then no refresh token is returned.

Going round in circles now.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried enabling logging?

Comment: Yes - logging enabled.  But nothing returned.

Comment: A 500 response is almost always the consequence of an uncaught exception, that should be automatically logged by Kestrel. Consider updating your question to include your complete logs (don't hesitate to change the verbosity level if necessary).

Comment: I've returned to this after rebuilding everything and updating libraries, and all working now.  I'm unable to see what was broken first time around.  But thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Do you happen to have a `UserInfoController` or something or anywhere you might require an instance of `UserManager` or `SignInManager` service with the wrong type of `IdentityUser`? I can remember that using `IdentityUser` instead of my own user type (let's call it `ApplicationUser`) in `UserInfoController` used to generate a similar error for me some time ago.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483589/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager-w)