# .ASP NET Core Identity - Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am tyrying to test and set-up Basic Identity logon page using the tutorial provided by Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio
I've followed those steps, the code was autogenerated. In order to test it, I've tried to run it. Main page was opening ok. When I navigated to Login page /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login I've got following error msg:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[WebApp.Areas.Identity.Data.WebAppUser]' while attempting to activate 'WebApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.

I have noticed similar questions and followed steps from one of them:
[Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager` while attempting to activate 'AuthController'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483589/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager-w)
I've tried to modify Startup.cs file as below:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Although it didn't resolved the problem.
I am attaching below current configuration:

Startup.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApp.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using WebApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account;

namespace WebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                   Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Login.cshtml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebApp.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace WebApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<WebAppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<WebAppUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<WebAppUser> signInManager, 
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<WebAppUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: replace your `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>` with `services.AddDefaultIdentity<WebAppUser>` - Actually the answer is right from the linked question you shared but looks like you misapplied the answers there.

Comment: Hello, sorry for long time to wait for reply.I have already done that, compiled project without errors, the ran it with IIS Express, the page throws error ```An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.```

Comment: that lacks a lot of detail, it may be from something wrong elsewhere. You firstly need to pinpoint it. Usually such an error would come with some error info & full stacktrace. You can see it in the *Output* window, via logging or on the developer exception page (in the development environment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you scaffold Identity **before** creating and implementing your customised usermodel, you will have to either scaffold Identity again (overwriting your previous pages) or manually replace every mention of IdentityUser in the Identity pages by your customised usermodel.

Your customised usermodel also needs to be mentioned in some of the following files: **ApplicationDbContext.cs**: This will be required.
For example:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser>
```

**Startup.cs**: This will be required.
For example:

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<CustomUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
```

**Program.cs**: Optional, if you're calling out to your applicationseeder methods from here, you'll want to pass along the UserManager service, which will need the customised usermodel.
For example:

```cs
var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<CustomUser>>();
```

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**: Optional, if you need to check if the user is signed in and with which role.
For example:

```html
@inject SignInManager<CustomUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<CustomUser> UserManager
```