# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. Identity View Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to display a name that's stored in a database when you go to user's profile. However i get this error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Website_friend_feature.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationUser' while
> attempting to activate
> 'Website_friend_feature.Controllers.UserController'.

I searched it and i did find an answer on here but it didn't work for me. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483589/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager-w)

When i implement the solution it says this schema already appears in program.cs. So i dont think that solution is for me. What am I doing wrong? Is it the way i'm calling the model in the view?

controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Website_friend_feature.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace Website_friend_feature.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ApplicationUser _AU;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public UserController (ApplicationUser AU, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _AU = AU;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Website_friend_feature.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Website_friend_feature.Data;

namespace Website_friend_feature
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            
            
            
            
            
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthDbContextConnection")));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();


            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you register `ApplicationUser` in your Dependency Injection graph?

Comment: @gunr2171 what do you mean

Comment: Your exception is telling you that you didn't register the service in DI. You should [learn about DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection).

Comment: @gunr2171 what do you need the startup.cs or programs.cs

Comment: If you're using a `Startup` class, then DI services are registered in the `Configure` method.

Comment: @gunr2171 im still stuck, i just updated the post with my startup

Comment: @gunr2171 nvm i figured it out myself, and why do you keep deleting code